# Remove white spaces from the beginning of each string in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, removing-whitespace

How do I remove the spaces at the beginning of each string in a list?

```
List = [' a', ' b', ' c']
```

Here is what I tried, but the list remained the same:

```
unique_items_1 = []

for i in unique_items:
    j = i.replace('^ +', '')
    unique_items_1.append(j)

print(List)
```

My expected result was:

```
List = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [str.lstrip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) in a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [' a', ' b', ' c']

my_list = [i.lstrip() for i in my_list]
print(my_list)  # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List = [' a',' b',' c']

print(List) # [' a', ' b', ' c']

List_Trimmed = [*map(lambda x: x.lstrip(), List)]

print(List_Trimmed) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the leading white spaces, you can use the [lstrip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) function.
In your case, for the list:

```
result = [x.lstrip() for x in List]
print(result)
```

For removing trailing spaces:

```
result = [x.rstrip() for x in List]
print(result)
```

The below code should work in general to remove all white spaces:

```
result = [x.replace(' ','') for x in List
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
for i in unique_items:
   j = i.strip()
   unique_items_1.append(j)
```

strip() removes spaces.

You can also use [lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip).